# Don't understand how Angular's Form Builder array works

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I don't understand how arrays work in reactive forms. All that I get is something like `No value accessor for form control with path 'myArray -> one -> one'`.

I'd appreciate someone that could explain to me how that works and how the template that I need should be done, thank you.

This is the .ts code where I get the structure from:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
  // [...]
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    myArray: this.fb.array([
      {
        one: this.fb.group({
          ...this.myList()
        })
      },
      {
        two: this.fb.group({
          ...this.myList()
        })
      },
      {
        three: this.fb.group({
          ...this.myList()
        })
      }
    ])
  });
}

myList() {
  return {
    one: new FormControl(false),
    two: new FormControl(false),
    three: new FormControl(false),
    four: new FormControl(false)
  };
}
```

and this is the .html where I should put the structure into:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFn()">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-card>

  <div formArrayName="myArray">
    <div *ngFor="let child of myForm.controls.myArray.controls; let i = index">
      <div formGroupName="">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-title>
            {{ myTitles[i}}
          </mat-card-title>
          <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item>
              <mat-checkbox formControlName="one">one</mat-checkbox>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
              <mat-checkbox formControlName="two">two</mat-checkbox>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
              <mat-checkbox formControlName="three">three</mat-checkbox>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
              <mat-checkbox formControlName="four">four</mat-checkbox>
            </mat-list-item>
          </mat-list>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Read this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the form group you want to acccess with `formControlName`, I'm not quite sure about `formGroupName`, but the value should either be "myArray" or "child" 
 what should work, in every case, and what I already used myself is use: `[formGroup]="child"` instead of `formGroupName`